# Excel Chart with two Y axes

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a question about creating an excel chart with two Y axes. Suppose I have the following data:

```
         Horizontal Axis    Primary Vertical Axis    Secondary Vertical Axis
Series 1     1                    0.5                         5.7
             2                    0.2                         6.3
             3                    0.3                         6.2
             4                    0.8                         4.8
             5                    0.4                         4.2

Series 2     1                    0.3                         5.1
             2                    0.5                         7.2
             3                    0.2                         6.4
             4                    0.6                         6.1
             5                    0.4                         4.9
```

I want to create a scatter plot with two lines from the data above, where the primary vertical axis data is read on the left side of the graph and the secondary vertical axis data is read on the right.

The only information I have found is how to insert entirely new series' for the information that will be read from the secondary axis, but this is not what I want to do. If I did that I would end up with 4 lines on the chart (2 for the primary axis and 2 for the secondary axis). Instead, I only want to have 2 lines on the chart that read from both the primary and secondary vertical axis at the same time. In other words, each line should be plotted as having two independent variables (one for each vertical axis).

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly, I want both lines to have 2 independent variables (one on each vertical axis).

Comment: If you want one dependent variable to map to two independent variables then you need a 3D chart.

Comment: Select the first series data and follow the instructions in the proposed duplicate to plot the values on two axes.  Then add the second series, replicating the settings of the first.

Comment: @fixer1234,  I think this Question has been asked in recent past also !! please mark it as Duplicate.

Comment: @RajeshS, I already voted it a dupe of the question Sandeep identified.  If you're aware of an additional duplicate, we can add that.  My comment above was because the identified dupe doesn't spell out how to expand the solution another dimension, so I added a hint.